# Can javascript capture image download times in the client?

Tags: javascript

With javascript event timers, you can relatively easily determine how long it too for the page to render in the browser, especially when using tools like [Jiffy](http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/). However, is it possible to capture more granular events such as individual image/object download times using javascript in the page? I am fairly sure this is not possible, but wanted to confirm with the javascript guru's of SO.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, unless you load the images using the javascript image object manually instead of in the markup, I don't believe this is possible.  that's why you usually see this functionality in things like firefox plugins

Comment: Sounds like it's impossible based on the rest of the answers :(

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to time can be put into an event that has a callback, you can check the time before and after. So anything you do with Ajax you can time. What exactly are you trying to time? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'd like to be able to time the download times of every image/object download on a specific page by inserting a generic javascript library webbug. Without having to modify the code. Something like Jiffy that I referenced above can time the entire page download, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get more granular than that.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Net tab in Firebug. I don't know if it can give you same information via Firebug Lite in other browsers or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally familiar with this jQuery plugin, but it may be of help to you:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers